# How do I make this save button save entered text onto a new page?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

```
- (IBAction)Save:(id)sender {

     NSString *saveString = taskName.text;
     NSUserDefaults *defults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     [defults setObject:saveString forKey:@"savedString"];
     [defults synchronize];
     //use data that has been given

}

- (IBAction)theTask:(id)sender {

     NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     NSString *loadstring = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedString"];
     [taskName setText:loadstring];
     [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Im trying to attach the new label i made on storyboard to attach to theTask method. So when the user types in a task and pushes save the task is placed in a list of other tasks

Comment: honestly I don't understand what is your problem, what does not work ? and why you call [super viewDidLoa] inside theTask: ?

Comment: And the random call to [super viewDidLoad] is just freaky...if you try to give a better explanation we will probably be able to help you!

Comment: Opps the [super viewDidLoad] was an accident. The issue is that i dont know how to make the saved sting appear in a list of tasks i created